# Zeitwerk "DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants" caused by including a module in the lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, deprecation-warning

`DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constants AuthHelper, SemanticFormHelper, ActionText::ContentHelper, and ActionText::TagHelper`

Since upgrading to Rails 6 I have been getting this warning relating to the new Zeitwerk autoloader.

Often this is caused by loading constants in the `config/initializers` folder, but that is not the case here.

`AuthHelper` and `SemanticFormHelper` are pulled in by these 2 files I have in my `lib` folder:

```
module AuthorizationSystem
  include AuthHelper
  ...
end
```

```
module SemanticFormBuilder
  include SemanticFormHelper
  ...
end
```

On initialization all the files in the `lib` folder are run, and anything included in those files trigger the `DEPRECATION WARNING`.

If I remove the `include` statements the warnings go away but then the app breaks on certain pages because the includes are necessary.

How can I have `include` statements in files in my `lib` folder without causing the warning?

`ActionText::ContentHelper` and `ActionText::TagHelper` are nowhere to be found in my app, so I imagine those warnings are coming from a gem I am using. Any ideas on how to debug that would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

To locate the source of your warnings, you can use the following code, placed in `application.rb`, before `Bundler.require`.

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller_base) do
  bc = ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner.new
  bc.remove_silencers!
  bc.add_silencer { |line| line.start_with?(RbConfig::CONFIG["rubylibdir"]) }
  bc.add_silencer { |line| line =~ Regexp.union(
    *(
      %w{ bootsnap railties spring activesupport actionpack zeitwerk thor rack }.
      map{|g| /\A#{g} \([\w.]+\) /}
    ),
    /\Abin\/rails/
  )}
  trace = bc.clean(caller)
  puts "Cleaned backtrace:\n\t#{trace.join("\n\t")}\n"
  puts "Most probably the cause is: #{trace.first}"
  puts "If not - uncomment `raise` at #{__FILE__}:#{__LINE__+1}"
  # raise "i can haz full backtrace"
  exit(1)
end
```

(from [GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36546#issuecomment-791736621))